# Array being returned as a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, adobe, extendscript

Experimenting with Adobe extension for After Effects, I'm using JSX to interface with the software and send information to a JS file, which updates the HTML UI panel.

At this point, I'm just trying to `console.log` some information coming back from the software (composition and layer names).

My problem is that what is supposed to be an `array` of `strings`, which I can play with on the JSX side, is received as a `string` once returned in my JS sheet.

Here is the flow:

**main.js**

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var csInterface = new CSInterface();

  function init() {
    themeManager.init();

    $("#btn_test").click(function() {
      csInterface.evalScript('main()', function(res) {
        console.log(typeof(res));
        console.log(res);
      });
    });
  }
  init();
}());
```

**hostscript.jsx**

```
function main() {
  var project = app.project;
  var comp = project.activeItem;
  var layers = comp.selectedLayers;
  var layersNames = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
    layersNames.push(layers[i].name);
  }
  return layersNames;
}
```

So in my console I receive both information:

- typeof is `string`
- logging res is `name1,name2`

Any ideas? I can't find a targeted answer on Stack Overflow or on any other Adobe-related forums.

Comment: `return [layersNames]` will return your array inside another array.

Comment: removing the brackets has no effect, it's still being returned as a string.

Comment: How do you *know* it's being returned as a string? oh wait I see. Well it may have to do with the way that API works.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `evalScript()` expects the script to return a string. You could JSON encode the array and then decode it.